# Unable to approve

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, contract-debugging, erc-20-approve

```
///
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
 import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
 import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
contract Trust { 
   
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  
  IERC20 public token;
  function q (IERC20 _token)public{
      _token.approve(msg.sender,100);
      
  }
}
///
```

What is the problem of approval

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you edited out important sections or if they are missing.

- Possibility 1 - the way you are testing
- Possibility 2 - msg.sender doesn't have 100 tokens to spend
- Possibility 3 - you haven't instantiated your token instance

In the example, `token` has no address for a contract that is actually deployed, just an interface to a hypothetical contract, i.e. a Type without a value.

You have to assign an address to that variable. For example:

```
constructor (address tokenAddr) public {
  token = IEROC20(tokenAddr);
}
```

Hope it helps.